# Split model Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I'm having a problem when I use the "Split model" option. What I want to do is basically hide these 10 water volumes:[image].

I select the tanks then I click on button for splitting with these options:
[image]

Final result is just what I want:

[image]

When I check the entire model to verify if everything is ok, these errors come out:

[image]

I've tried several things such as modifying the text part of the splitted model with no positive results, here's the original NOT modified

[image]

Can you please explain to me what kind of error it is? How can I resolve it? Thank you.

Edit: I'm using TIL library

Edit after Markus' answer: in the split model is it necessary to declare the type of liquid and change the portArray definition. I copied these lines of code and everything worked!

```
parameter TILMedia.LiquidTypes.BaseLiquid           liquidType = sim.liquidType1
"Liquid type" annotation (Dialog(tab="SIM",group="SIM"),choices(
choice=sim.liquidType1 "Liquid 1 as defined in SIM",
choice=sim.liquidType2 "Liquid 2 as defined in SIM",
choice=sim.liquidType3 "Liquid 3 as defined in SIM"));

replaceable package MediaConfiguration =
TIL.Utilities.MediaConfiguration
constrainedby TIL.Utilities.Internals.PartialMediaConfiguration
"Media and State Type Configuration" annotation (choicesAllMatching, Dialog(
    tab="SIM", group="Media Configuration"));
protected 
outer TIL.SystemInformationManager sim "System information manager";
```

and

```
public 
TIL.Connectors.LiquidPort portArray(
final liquidType=liquidType) ;
TIL.Connectors.LiquidPort portArray1(
final liquidType=liquidType) ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems to result from the vectorization of the connectors, that seems to get lost when using "split model". A bit difficult without the actual model, but:

Have you tried to modify the last two `connect` statements in `str3000` to:

```
connect(portArray, colume.portArray[1])
connect(portArray1, colume.portArray[2])
```

Additionally on the top level of the model, it seems you have connections to vectors of `str3000.portArray`. Try to remove them as they seem to be wrong, as you have two non-vector ports.
There should be something like `connect(str3000.portArray[1], ...)` and `connect(str3000.portArray1[2], ...)`, which should likely be changed to `connect(str3000.portArray, ...)` and `connect(str3000.portArray1, ...)`.

Comment: Thank you Markus! I read on your profile that you teach modeling and simulation, do you have perharps any course material regarding Modelica and Dymola?

Comment: Unfortunately, the book related to the lecture is in German, I assume that is not very helpful for you?

Comment: Some lecture slides are linked from here: https://www.modelica.org/education

Comment: @ Markus: unfortunately I don't speak German but maybe I can find someone who can translate it for me
@ Priyanka: thank you so much